# Controles de audio con HTML y JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un reproductor de musica. Lo que pretendo es que cuando le de a un boton realice esa acción. He creado eventos que los relacione con determinada funcion depende a la accion que se pulse. Pero en mi caso me falta algo para que funcione...
Esto es lo que tengo:

```
<script>

    myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    playAudio = document.getElementById("play");
    stopAudio = document.getElementById("stop");
    pausarAudio = document.getElementById("pause");

    //Añadiendo controles
    playAudio.addEventListener('click', playAudio, true);
    pausarAudio.addEventListener('click', pausar, true);
    stopAudio.addEventListener("click", stopAudio, true);


    function playAudio(){
        myAudio.load();
        myAudio.play();
    }
    function stopAudio(){
        myAudio.pause();
        myAudio.currentTime = 0; 
    }
    function pausar(){
        myAudio.pause();
    }
    </script>

    <audio id="myAudio" autoplay preload>
        <source src="Canciones/adictiva.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
    <!-- Reproductor MP3 -->
    <div class="mp3">
        <div class="screen">
            <p id="info-track">Adictiva</p>
        </div>
        <div class="controles">
            <button id="play">Play</button>
            <button id="pause">Pause</button>
            <button id="stop">Stop</button>
            <button id="primera">Primera</button>
            <button id="anterior">Anterior</button>
            <button id="siguiente">Siguiente</button>
            <button id="ultima">Ultima</button>
            <!-- Control para deslizar la barra de volumen y baja o subir volumen -->
            <button id="controlVolumen">Control de Volumen</button>
            <!-- Control para deslizar la barra para avanzar o retroceder la canción -->
            <button>Control deslizar</button>
            <button>Aleatorio</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿Porque usas el mismo nombre en tus funciones y en tus objetos? Podrías usar `playBtn` para tu objeto, es más legible.

Comment: No se a que te refieres Mauricio pero si quieres ponerme un ejemplo de como lo harias tu .. estoy muy perdido con esto...

Comment: En términos generales está bien. Excepto que yo cambiaría el nombre de mis objetos. Tu los tienes así: `playAudio = document.getElementById("play");` y yo los colocaría así: `playBtn = document.getElementById("play");`. Esto es porque luego declaras tus funciones `playAudio`, `pauseAudio`, etc. Y los nombres ya han sido declarados para tus objetos. No se si captas lo que trato de decirte. No puedes usar el mismo nombre para tus objetos y para tus funciones.

Comment: Si si te entiendo, he cambiado ya todos los nombres de mis objetos como bien has dicho, pero me sigue sin funcionar, es que no lo entiendo... tengo todos los metodos bien y hago correctamente la llamada a cada metodo cuando le doy click a un boton...

Comment: Vale ya esta solucionado Mauricio, lo que faltaba era colocar el script por debajo del codigo del HTML... no habia caido... porque el navegador va leyendo el documento HTML de arriba hacia abajo y primero se encuentra con el script y claro cuando lo ejecuta no hace nada

Comment: Excelente. Publica tu solución como respuesta. Dando los detalles del problema y la solución al mismo. Asi ayudas a otros que tengan la misma situación. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Bien ya esta solucionado. Lo que pasaba es que el codigo javascript que esta situado en la etiqueta script debe ir al final del body del HTML. Y yo lo tenia por encima de los botones y la etiqueta audio por eso no funcionaba. Aparte de esto, mis objetos y mis funciones se llamaban igual. Lo he editado para que tenga un correcto funcionamiento. Asi ha quedado:

```
<div class="mp3">
        <div class="screen">
            <p id="info-track"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="controles">
            <button id="play">Play</button>
            <button id="pause">Pause</button>
            <button id="stop">Stop</button>
            <button id="primera">Primera</button>
            <button id="anterior">Anterior</button>
            <button id="siguiente">Siguiente</button>
            <button id="ultima">Ultima</button>
            <!-- Control para deslizar la barra de volumen y baja o subir volumen -->
            <button id="controlVolumen">Control de Volumen</button>
            <!-- Control para deslizar la barra para avanzar o retroceder la canción -->
            <button>Control deslizar</button>
            <button>Aleatorio</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    //Objeto con referencia a la etiqueta audio     
    myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    //Objeto con referencia al boton play
    playBtn = document.getElementById("play");
    //Objeto con referencia al boton pause
    pauseBtn = document.getElementById("pause");
    //Objeto con referencia al boton stop
    stopBtn = document.getElementById("stop");


    //Añadiendo funcionalidad a los botones del reproductor
    playBtn.addEventListener("click", play, true);
    pauseBtn.addEventListener("click", pause, true);
    stopBtn.addEventListener("click", stop, true);
    console.log(myAudio.currentSrc);

    function play(){
        myAudio.play();
    }
    function stop(){
        myAudio.pause();
        myAudio.currentTime = 0; 
    }
    function pause(){
        myAudio.pause();
    }
    </script>
```